# Make parallax work on iOS without background-attachment:fixed

Tags: html, css, parallax, web-development-server

Does anyone know if there is a reasonable way to make this parallax background scrolling effect work on iOS devices?  Here is the page I am working on.
http://districtdentalontheouachita.com/new/

Right now all I am doing to achieve this effect is to used background-attachment: fixed;

Here is the css for my sections

```
.section1 {
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url("images/dental1.jpg");
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

The client really wants this effect but I cant make it work on iOS...

Answer (score 2):

Use `position: fixed` instead and then some placement adjustments.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

This, with some z-index, could get the effect on any device. It is unfortunate that ios does not work with `background-attachment: fixed` but there is always another way.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).